# Location of Sqoop installation on Amazon EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqoop, amazon-emr

I started an EMR cluster in order to use test out sqoop but it turns out it doesnt seem to be installed on the latest version of EMR(5.19.0) as I didnt find it in the directory `/usr/lib/sqoop`. I tried 5.18.0 as well but it was missing there too.

According to the [application versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html#emr-5190-app-versions) page, sqoop 1.4.7 should be installed on the cluster.

The [EMR console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOM7c.png) gives me a list of 4 "installations". I chose the Core Hadoop package. It has Hive, Hue, etc installed in `/usr/lib`. Am I missing something here? It's my first time using EMR or sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the "Advanced Options" link at the top of the "Create Cluster" page where I can select individual software to install.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an EMR cluster, use the advanced options link where it allows you to select sqoop.